# How do I delete Western Digital SmartWare from my drive?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a MyBook’s “WD SmartWare” virtual CD from my desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/44318/how-do-i-remove-a-mybooks-wd-smartware-virtual-cd-from-my-desktop)

If I don't want it on my drive how do I delete it? I've tried delete it from the drive with zero success. I've delete the software on my previous with no issues until now. I've even tried changing the files from read only and I'm still unable to remove the software.

Comment: A related question: http://superuser.com/questions/44318/how-do-i-remove-a-mybooks-wd-smartware-virtual-cd-from-my-desktop there they also didn't really find a solution.

Comment: Plus what OS are you using?

Comment: Ever tried deleting the partition or formatting the drive?

Answer (score 2):

> The Virtual CD is the build into the
>   firmware of the drive. There is no
>   option to remove the virtual CD.

According to [link text](https://superuser.com/questions/44318/how-do-i-remove-a-mybooks-wd-smartware-virtual-cd-from-my-desktop/46992#46992)

Answer (score 1):

See if this article applies to your case:
[A Workaround for removing Western Digital’s SmartWare Virtual CD Partition](http://acletras.com/2009/09/28/a-workaround-for-removing-western-digitals-smartware-virtual-cd-partition/comment-page-1/)

Even if the described software doesn't apply to your O/S, I'm sure you can build a similar solution with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **[Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)** to remove an undeletable file [as suggested by Geeks are Sexy](http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2007/06/04/how-to-delete-an-undeletable-file/)

> Unlocker is a very useful freeware
>   that will allow you to unlock any
>   files that are currently in use by
>   Windows. You’ll know if this is
>   happening if you are getting any of
>   these messages when trying to delete a
>   file:
>
> - Cannot delete file: Access is denied
> - There has been a sharing violation
> - The source or destination file may be in use
> - The file is in use by another program or user
> - Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is
>     not currently in use
>
> Unlocker will make things right again
>   for you.
>
> You’ll notice that right after
>   installing the software, a new option
>   named “unlocker” will appear when
>   right clicking any files or folders in
>   Windows Explorer. To unlock a locked
>   file, just right click it, select
>   unlocker, and the unlocker software
>   will start. Then, click “unlock all”
>   and close the software. Now that your
>   file is unlocked, just delete it in
>   Windows Explorer, as you always do.
>   This is much simpler than solution #1
>   or #2, isn’t it? I hope these three
>   solutions will help you get rid of
>   those hard to delete files!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried the program just the other day and it didn't work but thanks.