# WD smartware 1tb drive Unlock

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a drive where the usb on the chip broke and can not access the hard drive because of the smatware password.If i plug in hardrive I can re format, but how do i access the drive to recover my files before resetting the drive. i know my password, but cannot access the smatware software to unlock the drive any one have any ideas. WD says I have to go to datareceovery for over $400 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firmware to remove the smartware altogether?

See this question: [**How do I remove a MyBook's “WD SmartWare” virtual CD from my desktop?**](https://superuser.com/questions/44318/how-do-i-remove-a-mybooks-wd-smartware-virtual-cd-from-my-desktop)

You can also give [**TestDisk**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a try, it's saved me many times for data recovery purposes but may also be able to read past the smartware lock.